# Taurus downloads Jmeter from Internet instead of referring to Local installation

Tags: jmeter, taurus

Need to have Taurus refer to my local Jmeter version instead of downloading from Internet. The issue is my corporate network is behind proxy and blocks the jmeter download.

Taurus tries to download jmeter from internet (https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-4.0.zip) when I run the bzt command. Even though I have provided my local Jmeter setup bin directory in 'Path' Environment variable, it still tries to download from internet.

I have also tried manually putting the local jmeter files under ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/{version} folder but it sill doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to provide existing JMeter installation is via `.bzt-rc` file (it should live in your current user home folder)

Default configuration looks like

```
# JMeter settings

#modules:
#  jmeter:
#    properties:  # JMeter properties for every JMeter run
#      prop_name: prop value
#    system-properties:  # Java system properties
#      sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders: "true"
#    memory-xmx: 4G  # allow JMeter to use up to 4G of memory
#    path: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/{version}/bin/jmeter  # path to local jmeter installation
#    version: 3.2  # version to use
#    plugins:  # plugins to install
#    - jpgc-json=2.2
#    - jmeter-ftp
#    - jpgc-casutg
```

You need to amend at least `path:` section to point to your local JMeter deployment.

References:

- [JMeter Location & Auto-Installation](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Location-Auto-Installation)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)